# Gnuplot fitting with Gauss result in different surfaces, why?

Tags: data, gnuplot

I have a question related to the surface generation with gnuplot, or lets say with the fitting procedure. I have different curves which does not follow a mathematical formula but I need to use these data within my CFD code. However, to reach this goal, I map the discrete curvature data points (x, y, z) to a 2D surface with the Gaussian fitting algorithm. I am using the following mapping syntax:

```
# Surface with 800 x 800 discrete points dx = 4, dy = 6500 for
# for adjusting the Gaussian profile to the x, y axis
set dgrid3d 800 800 gauss 4,6500
set table "Look-Up-Table.txt"
splot "globalFile.txt" using 2:5:($3/1000000) title "Look-Up-Table"
```

I expect to get one surface for the fitting procedure but I realized that the output file contains a lot of more surfaces. Why is it like that? The file could look like that:

```
# Surface 0 of 13 surfaces
# Curve title: "Look up table"
# IsoCurve 0, 800 points
# x y z type
...
#
# Survace 1 of 13 surfaces
# IsoCurve 0, 800 points
# x y z type
....
```

Any suggestion is welcomed. 
I wanted to upload some test case but I am not allowed to share the data but I hope you get the point. Just one additional info. The data points that I want to map are following some surface but within one area I have a lot of fluctuations. Could this be the reason for the additional surfaces?

Thanks in advance,
Tobi

Comment: Possibly you have too many columns in your data file. What is the output of `awk '{print NF; exit}' globalFile.txt` ? BTW, are the files originating in windows? if so, did you remember to convert them to unix?

Comment: Dear Dani_l, thanks for your feedback ... I am a Linux user so I am not working in windows but thanks for the hint. I figured out why I have so many different surface. In fact it was related to the globalFile.txt which had a lot of data that should not be included. I made a mistake in my c++ code which manipulates the data and saves them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was in fact the globalFile.txt. There were to many data points included more often than once and also some data which does not belong to the data (as also mentioned by @Dani_l) . However, changing my c++ code that manipulates and generates the data file was everything that has to be done. Now the fitting procedure is working again as expected.